# How to block wind between rooms

Tags: windows

I am living in an old (renovated) flat which size 25 m2 in Riga. 
However, there is the wind feeling all the time.
There is very bad isolation in the corridor. 
In my apartment, there is no isolating door between two rooms.

This apartment is not my apartment so I am not going to invest much to it.

What is a good way to decrease to amount of windy feeling in the apartment?
Some Chinese curtains or something isolating material in front of the window?

Comment: Do both rooms have heating vents or radiators in each room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know around here there is a kind of temporary transparent caulking that can be put around windows and such to prevent air flow. In the winter, it prevents cold air to come in, and in the summer it can be put around window air conditioning units to prevent warm air from coming in and cool air from going out.

This type of caulking is easy to remove at the end of the season.

Last year we used plastic film taped around the windows to prevent air from coming in. This year we'll try that caulk, which worked very well during the summer.

If air is coming from under your main door, you could try and put a towel when the door is closed, or a carpet, even.

(The goal here is to prevent air from even coming into your apartment.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have to buy some caulking silicone and then a carpet here. It feels freezing here.

Comment: I put up plastic a lot. Use a hair dryer to shrink it to the right size and you have a nice additional barrier for a few dollars/window.

Answer (score 1):

**[Air Sealing Your Home](http://energy.gov/energysaver/articles/air-sealing-your-home)** -energy.gov

---

Although there are some good suggestions here, I hate temporary solutions to permanent problems. Your main one being [AIR INFILTRATION](https://www.energystar.gov/index.cfm?c=new_homes_features.hm_f_reduced_air_infiltration).

[image]

[How to install a door sweep](http://www.diynetwork.com/how-to/how-to-install-a-door-sweep/index.html).

[image]

[How to seal windows and doors](http://thecraftsmanblog.com/how-to-install-spring-bronze-weatherstripping/).

---

In Chicago, from September 15th to June 1st, "it is the landlord’s responsibility to ensure that the heater can heat the **entire unit** to 68 in the day and 66 at night. If there is a problem, then the landlord needs to know about it. A written letter will help with documentation." -John Bartlett, [tenants-rights.org](http://www.tenants-rights.org/heat-other-essential-services-faq/)