# How can I seal air leaks and otherwise winterize, as a renter?

Tags: winterizing, rental, temporary

As winter arrives I am finding cold air leaks all over my apartment. Various parts of my sliding windows, light switches, power outlets, etc. Unfortunately, I rent, so caulk and expanding foam aren't options for me. I need solutions that aren't quite permanent, and won't do too much damage when they are removed.

I know about weather stripping for the non-sliding parts of my doors and windows. I don't have a good idea for the parts that slide against each other (like the tracks for the window).

I can put plastic child-proof plugs in the electrical outlets to stop air from coming straight out of those holes, but that doesn't help with leaks between the outlet and the faceplate, or between the faceplate and the wall. Is there some sort of tape I can put there, preferably clear or available in colors that might match my faceplates?

PS: Of course I am also going to use curtains.

Comment: Similar question with my answer: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49837/how-to-block-wind-between-rooms/49839#49839

Comment: I seriously doubt your landlord would object if you did a little caulking / spackling, especially if you were tidy about it.

Answer (score 2):

For outlets, there are pre-cut foam gaskets that fit under the faceplates. You could leave those or remove when you go, as you prefer.

For windows that you will leave closed all winter, shrink film window sealing kits cover the whole window (best to put them all the way to the outside edge of the frame) and are fairly clear and non-obtrusive once shrunk, plus they seal the whole window (frame and all) if done that way. Peel them off in the spring.

I have used removable caulk on one building. Horribly stinky stuff, but it did peel off with no damage in the spring.

Comment: the foam gaskets aren't as airtight as I'd like. And I'm hoping for something to do to the windows before I put plastic over them.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this weatherseal tape for a couple of years now: [Frost King Weatherseal Tape](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000SL0NIA). It does a good job of sealing around leaky window frames. Of course you have to pull it off in the spring (except on windows you don't need to open). Seems to be good at not pulling off paint (not perfect!).

I prefer it to the shrink film, because I find that obscures the view.

Answer (score 0):

for sliding doors, use something like this:

[http://www.amazon.com/Prime-Line-Products-8659-Weatherstrip-18-Feet/dp/B000LNS8DM/ref=pd_cp_hi_2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LNS8DM)

It is a form of weatherstripping specific for sliding doors/windows.

Have a warm winter!

Fellow renter

Answer (score 0):

Window shrink-wrap kits can be a significant improvement. (They're basically low-cost/disposable interior storm windows.)

Answer (score 0):

Peal and seal is a product that is like silicone but it is easily removeable when you want to remove it and it drys almost instantly..  I've only seen it in clear color but it is wonderful stuff.  If you have ever gotten a credit card in the mail, its the "gummy" adhesive they use on the back of the card to secure it to the paper.